Rotating a vector field in an efficient way in python
I need to rotate a 3D vector field by 90 degrees. I do that by first using the NumPy function rot90 (see the docs here). Then I rotate each component at each position in a very inefficient way: using nested for loops. It works fine, as can be seen for example by the following two figures: on the left you see the original vector field, where all vectors simply point into the x-direction, on the right the whole field is rotated by 90 degrees. It works as intended, but it is implemented in a very inefficient way, making it almost useless when I come to large array (e.g. 100x200x400).

This is my implementation:
# import standard modules
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

def define_3D_vector_field( Nx=30, Ny=40, Nz=50,
                            direction='x'
                          ):
    # initialze empty arrays, one for each vector component
    vecfield_x  = np.zeros( (Nx, Ny, Nz) )
    vecfield_y  = np.zeros( (Nx, Ny, Nz) )
    vecfield_z  = np.zeros( (Nx, Ny, Nz) )

    if direction == 'x':
        vecfield_x[ round(.25*Nx):round(.75*Nx), 
                    round(.25*Ny):round(.75*Ny), 
                    round(.25*Nz):round(.75*Nz) ] = 1.

    return vecfield_x, vecfield_y, vecfield_z

def make_simple_3Dvecfield_plot( vecfield_x, vecfield_y, vecfield_z ):
    fig1    = mlab.figure( bgcolor=(1,1,1), fgcolor=(0,0,0),
                           size=(800,600),
                         )

    src = mlab.pipeline.vector_field( vecfield_x, vecfield_y, vecfield_z )
    mlab.pipeline.vectors(src, mask_points=20, scale_factor=4.)

    mlab.xlabel('x')
    mlab.ylabel('y')
    mlab.zlabel('z')
    mlab.outline()

    mlab.show()

def rot90vecfield(vecfield_x, vecfield_y, vecfield_z, rot_axis='y'):    
    theta   = np.radians(90.)

    if rot_axis == 'y':
        vf_x = np.rot90(vecfield_x, k=1, axes=(2,0))
        vf_y = np.rot90(vecfield_y, k=1, axes=(2,0))
        vf_z = np.rot90(vecfield_z, k=1, axes=(2,0))

        # NOTE: this requires the transposed matrix to work correctly
        rot_mat = np.array( [ [np.cos(theta) , 0., np.sin(theta)  ],
                              [0.            , 1., .0             ],
                              [-np.sin(theta), 0.,  np.cos(theta) ] ] ).T

    vf_x_tmp = np.copy(vf_x)
    vf_y_tmp = np.copy(vf_y)
    vf_z_tmp = np.copy(vf_z)

    for xx in range(vecfield_x.shape[0]):
        for yy in range(vecfield_x.shape[1]):
            for zz in range(vecfield_x.shape[2]):
                vec_xyz = np.dot( rot_mat, np.array( [vf_x_tmp[zz,yy,xx], 
                                                      vf_y_tmp[zz,yy,xx],
                                                      vf_z_tmp[zz,yy,xx]] ) )
                vf_x[ zz, yy, xx ] = vec_xyz[0]
                vf_y[ zz, yy, xx ] = vec_xyz[1]
                vf_z[ zz, yy, xx ] = vec_xyz[2]

    return vf_x, vf_y, vf_z

def main():
    vf_x, vf_y, vf_z = define_3D_vector_field()
    make_simple_3Dvecfield_plot( vf_x, vf_y, vf_z )

    vf_x, vf_y, vf_z = rot90vecfield( vf_x, vf_y, vf_z )
    make_simple_3Dvecfield_plot( vf_x, vf_y, vf_z )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

I am pretty sure there is some nice little algebra which I can apply, I just can't get my head around it. Any hints on how to make this more efficient (memory-wise and computation-wise) would be greatly appreciated!

Instead of rotating every point/vector in the scene, just rotate your axes.

@user24714692, questions like this are answered all the time on SO.  There are more numpy experts hanging around here.  Plus CR tends to be pickier about how complete the work code needs to be.

@Woodford sorry, I guess I don't get what you mean, but rotating the axes is the same as doing the initial rot90, then I still need to rotate every single vector of my vector field...?

You can use tensordot(), which is more efficient:
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab


def define_3D_vectors(Nx=30, Ny=40, Nz=50, direction='x'):
    x = np.zeros((Nx, Ny, Nz))
    y = np.zeros((Nx, Ny, Nz))
    z = np.zeros((Nx, Ny, Nz))

    if direction == 'x':
        x[round(.25 * Nx):round(.75 * Nx),
          round(.25 * Ny):round(.75 * Ny),
          round(.25 * Nz):round(.75 * Nz)] = 1.

    return x, y, z


def plot_3D_vectors(x, y, z):
    fig1 = mlab.figure(bgcolor=(1, 1, 1), fgcolor=(0, 0, 0), size=(1200, 800))
    src = mlab.pipeline.vector_field(x, y, z)
    mlab.pipeline.vectors(src, mask_points=10, scale_factor=5.)
    mlab.xlabel('x')
    mlab.ylabel('y')
    mlab.zlabel('z')
    mlab.outline()
    mlab.show()


def get_rotated(x, y, z, axis='y'):
    theta = np.radians(90)
    if axis == 'y':
        RM = np.array([[np.cos(theta), 0, np.sin(theta)],
                       [0, 1, 0],
                       [-np.sin(theta), 0, np.cos(theta)]])

    V = np.stack((x, y, z), axis=-1)
    R = np.tensordot(V, RM, axes=((3,), (1,)))
    return R[..., 0], R[..., 1], R[..., 2]


def main():
    x, y, z = define_3D_vectors()
    plot_3D_vectors(x, y, z)
    rx, ry, rz = get_rotated(x, y, z)
    plot_3D_vectors(rx, ry, rz)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


Prints



Note:

Also transpose (.T) is not necessary for the RM.


tensordot uses reshape and transpose to reduced dimensions that dot can handle. Here all it has to do is use stack.reshape(-1,3) to get the coorodinates into a (Nx*Ny*Nz, 3) 2d array..

If vf_x etc are (Nx,Ny,Nz) shape, and rot_mat is (3,3), you could combine the points into a
(Nx,Ny,Nz,3,1) field array

and use matmul to rotate the whole thing without the loops
newfield = rot_mat @ field

That is matmul/@ does dot on the last 2 dimensions, and 'batches' the leading ones.  newfield should have the same shape.
test case
To illustrate without your plotting etc, make a simple (2,2) array of points (oops, should that be (2,2,2)?):
In [373]: vf = np.arange(1,5).reshape(2,2)    
In [374]: vfx,vfy,vfz = vf*1, vf*2, vf*3

And 90 deg rot matrix:
In [377]: theta=np.pi*.5;rot_mat = np.array( [ [np.cos(theta) , 0., np.sin(theta)  ],
     ...:                               [0.            , 1., .0             ],
     ...:                               [-np.sin(theta), 0.,  np.cos(theta) ] ] ).T

In [378]: rot_mat
Out[378]: 
array([[ 6.123234e-17,  0.000000e+00, -1.000000e+00],
       [ 0.000000e+00,  1.000000e+00,  0.000000e+00],
       [ 1.000000e+00,  0.000000e+00,  6.123234e-17]])

Use stack to join the arrays on a new last dimension:
In [379]: field = np.stack((vfx,vfy,vfz),-1)    
In [380]: field.shape
Out[380]: (2, 2, 3)

And rotate:
In [381]: newfield = rot_mat @ field[...,None]

In [382]: newfield.shape
Out[382]: (2, 2, 3, 1)


In [385]: field
Out[385]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 2,  4,  6]],

       [[ 3,  6,  9],
        [ 4,  8, 12]]])

In [387]: newfield[...,0]
Out[387]: 
array([[[ -3.,   2.,   1.],
        [ -6.,   4.,   2.]],

       [[ -9.,   6.,   3.],
        [-12.,   8.,   4.]]])

This needs fudging, but I think the basic idea of using a multidimensional matmul to replace the iterated dot remains workable.

Note that for theta = np.radians(90.), things can be even more optimized since sin(theta) = 1 and cos(theta) = 0, but it is not clear if theta may be another value in the future.

I chose the .5pi at random. Should have used ,25 to be more interesting. Though eyeballing the result coulb be easier with 90deg.
